# Which tense is: "it is intolerable to think this storm leading up to some conference"

Tags: tense, future-constructions

> It is intolerable to think of this storm of universal distress leading
> up to nothing but some "conference" of diplomatists out of touch with the world, with secret sessions, ambiguous "understandings".

*- The new world order by H.G. Wells*

What tense is in the "leading up to" part?
Is it future tense? Does it means: it is hard this think that the storm will lead to conference?

Or is it in some continuous tense, like: It is hard to think that the storm is leading us to conference?

And what does the word "with" belong to in "with secret sessions". The diplomats with secret sessions?

Or conferences with secret sessions? If so then does the "ambiguous understandings" belong to secret sessions too?

Comment: It's impossible to answer since your question is based on the mistaken premise that the phrase "leading up to" is in a tense. It's not. The phrase "leading up to" is part of the gerund phrase "this storm of universal distress leading up to..." Gerunds are nouns. That gerund phrase is a noun phrase that serves as the object of the preposition "of." The tense of the sentence itself is present tense, which is conveyed by the present tense conjugation "is."

Comment: I'd call that a perfectly good answer.  You're allowed to put "Your question is slightly wrong and here's why" in an Answer on SE, "frame challenge" is the jargon.  And I was wondering whether that was a gerund but wasn't sure myself until I saw your comment!

Answer (score 1):

> It is intolerable to think of this storm of universal distress leading up to nothing but some "conference" of diplomatists out of touch with the world, with secret sessions, ambiguous "understandings".

*lead up to something* is a phrasal verb.  *leading up to something* is its present participle form.

> — phrasal verb with lead verb

> C2

> If a period of time or series of events leads up to an event or activity, it happens until that event or activity begins:

> The pilot had no recollection of the events leading up to the crash.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lead-up-to-sth)

With *leading up to*, your example means this universal distress is like a series of events having no solution but creating some conferences.

Edit after comments from A.B.

*with secret sessions* refers to the diplomats using secret sessions for discussions.  In *ambiguous understandings*, *understandings* is used to mean vague informal agreements between the parties.

> an informal agreement between people

> It took several hours of discussion before they could come to/reach an understanding.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/understanding)

> with preposition (METHOD)

> using something

[With](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with)

Comment: The phrase *ambiguous "understandings"* here doesn't mean that the diplomats didn't understand something clearly.  "Understandings" is being used in a specialised sense here, as Wells hints by the use of quote marks - "an understanding" in diplomacy means a vague informal agreement between two sides.  (This also appears in contexts other than diplomacy sometimes - "There was no written contract, but there was an understanding".

Answer (score 0):

"Leading up to" is a phrasal verb, not the main verb, and does not have a tense.

> Does it means: it is hard this think that the storm will lead to conference?

No. What it means is that this "this storm of universal distress"  (World War I?  Or some lesser but still horrible disaster) appears to result in nothing more than a lot of diplomatic argy-bargy.  They would meet in a conference, have secret sessions, come to "understandings" that do not actually commit to anything, and on the whole, despite the scale and suffering of the cataclysm, ensure that nothing really changes.

Contemplating how all that suffering lead to nothing is "intolerable"   --excruciatingly painful.